# How to disable some cells in a List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a List. I want to disable first cell. How can I do it?

I set `.disabled(true)` but it doesn't work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<5) {
                Text("\($0)")
                .disabled($0 == 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still can touch first cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

Here's [a link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269586-allowshittesting)!